# R Shiny DT Row Select and Row Edit Collision

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a Shiny app that I am working on and am using `renderDataTable` to display a data frame to the user.  Right now, the user needs to click on a row of the table to pull up additional information about that row.  At the same time, I have the data table set to be 'row' editable.  This is really causing some problems.  In order to initiate the edit mode for the row, one needs to double click on the row, but clicking multiple times toggles the selected state of the row.

Is there a way to initiate the row editing without having to double click or to disable the row selection status when a double click is present?

EDIT:  Here is my invocation of the DT:

```
output$image_list = DT::renderDataTable({
    if(!('data.frame' %in% class(values$images))) {
        return(NULL)
    }
    
        datatable(values$images,
                  rowname=FALSE,
                  options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(0, 1, 3, 6)))), 
                  colnames=c('ID', 'Full File Name', 'Filename', 'Directory', 'Range Scale', 'Heading', 'Status'),
                  selection = 'single',
                  editable = list(target='row', disable = list(columns=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 6)))
        ) %>%
            formatStyle('Status', target='row', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c('Incomplete', 'Complete'), c('#FF9999', '#99FF99')))
})
```

Version Information

```
Tool | Version
-----|--------
R    | 4.0 
Shiny| 1.5.0 
DT   | 0.15
```

Comment: It's hard to understand without the details. How do you attach a click listener to the rows?  Can't you attach it to only one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand but maybe this can help. With the app below, you can select a row only by clicking on a cell in a non-editable column. So, double-clicking an editable cell doesn't trigger the row selection. Not sure this helps... tell me what.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- iris[1:6,]
nonEditableColumns <- c(3, 4)


ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat, 
      extensions = "Select",
      selection = "none",
      editable = list(
        target = "row", 
        disable = list(columns = nonEditableColumns)
      ),
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(className = "selectable", targets = nonEditableColumns),
          list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
        ),
        select = list(style = "single",
                      selector = "td.selectable")
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Is there a similar thing but for rows? Searched for `rowDefs` in docs to no avail